# Firestore returns empty list in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm having problem in getting data from firestore.I can see all the document exist in firestore collection.But it returns empty list inside stream builder. Here is my code:

```
// Chat Screen.Dart

   class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static final routeName = "/chat";

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Inbox"),),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: DatabaseService.instance.getUserId(),
          builder: (context, idSnap) {
            if (idSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              print("id snap :${idSnap.data}");
              return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: DatabaseService.instance.chatListStream(idSnap.data),
                  builder: (context, chatsSnap) {
                    if (chatsSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text("waiting for the data");
                    } else if (chatsSnap.hasError) {
                      return Text('error ${chatsSnap.error}');
                    } else {
                      print("has data");
                      print("document found: ${chatsSnap.data.docs.length}"); // it prints 0 
                      return Text("data is loaded");
                    }
                  });
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          }
      ),
    );
  }


 
// DatabaseService.dart

class DatabaseService{
 
  DatabaseService._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseService instance = DatabaseService._privateConstructor();
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<String>getUserId() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userId = prefs.getString('user_id') ?? '0';
    return userId;
  }
 
  Stream<QuerySnapshot>chatListStream(String userId){
    return firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('chatList').snapshots();
  }
 
}
```

I have checked The collection and document title which is correct and the userId being passed is not null and valid data.Here is the Screenshot of firestore database :

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: print("id snap :${idSnap.data}"); did you get a valide id ?

Comment: yes it gives valid id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at how the documents in the `chatList` subcollection(s) are displayed in an **italic** font: this means that, in the console, these documents are only present as "container" (or "placeholder") of one or more sub-collection(s) but that they are not "genuine" documents, i.e. they don't exist in the Firestore database. **Therefore querying documents in one of these `chatList` subcollections will return an empty QuerySnapshot.**

You have probably created documents directly under a sub-collection of each of these `chatList` documents, without creating the `chatList` documents themselves.

---

So, in your case, if you need to have genuine docs in the `chatList` collections, you need to create them at the same time you create the first subcollection doc.

Also, note that Cloud Firestore has shallow reads: querying for documents in a collection doesn't pull in data from subcollections.